# Targeting Mvvmcross 6.0 for MonoDroid v8.0

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to create a Android project with MvvmCross.
But I'm trying to target MonoDroid 8.0 which is API-26 Android Oreo 8.0. Cause my test device is this and cannot be upgraded to 8.1.

But when trying to install any Mvvmcross.Droid package I get a

> Package MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Design 6.0.1 is not compatible with
>   monoandroid80 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0)

Does that mean if I'm trying to target any older version other than 8.1 I cannot use Mvvmcross 6.0 and have to use older versions of Mvvmcross?

Comment: Try change your Android compile version.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT : Yes set the target platform to 8.0 but doesn't help.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith 8.1 is minimum. You can still run it on older devices.

Comment: @Cheesebaron : Yes finally solved it by installing the 8.1 (27) sdk and then changing the Target Platform to 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else if facing a similar problem.

Note : MVVMCross 6 targets minimum MonoDroid 8.1 which is API 27 and you need to install them in order for the app to compile and run on any versions of Android.

So solved this by installing the API 27 sdk and making sure the Target Version is set to API 27 or 8.1 version.